# Android Studio Empty test suite

Tags: android, testing, android-studio

i have a problem adding tests to my android application.
If i want to run my example-test the following error occurs:

`Running tests
Test running startedTest running failed: Unable to find instrumentation info for: ComponentInfo{xxx/android.test.InstrumentationTestRunner}
Empty test suite.`

My test class looks like this:

```
public class ExampleTest extends AndroidTestCase {

public void test() throws Exception {
    final int expected = 1;
    final int reality = 5;
    assertEquals(expected, reality);
    }
}
```

The strange thing is that it works all well in a different project which contains of just one module.
In that small testing project the project structure doesnt matter. I tried everything.
The Structure with src/androidTest/java/my.package.test worked as well as to put the test class directly somewhere into my real sources.
There is also no need to specify an instrumentation runner in the run configuration or in the build.gradle.

But in my real Project it doesn't work at all. What else i can try?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It came out that i had to change the build type to debug indeed.
For some inexplicable reason it won't work with a custom build type, although it works with my small example project.

Comment: Thx sooooo much! I have to add that if you are testing a lib module inside a project, make sure you the lib is using a build type debug!

Comment: Mine is already **debug** type, and it doesn't solve the problem.

Answer (score -1):

In my case I instantiated a class in the constructor and that caused the "Empty test suite".

```html
public class ApplicationTest extends ApplicationTestCase<Application> {
    private MyClass mc;

    public ApplicationTest() {
        super(Application.class);

        mc = new MyClass(this.getContext());
    }

    ....
}
```

Comment: That only applies to Android test cases for Activities, Views, etc., not `AndroidTestCase`.